# Где найти базу распространенных имен, фамилий и отчеств?

Tags: поиск-данных

Хотелось бы найти в JSON, XML, SQL (предпочтительные форматы) форматах базу данных, где есть все российские ФИО. В идеале, конечно, чтобы еще и их склонения были (Иван - Ивану - Ивана - Иваном...).
Есть ли такие данные в открытом виде?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rai220/russian-cyrillic-names-and-sex вот к примеру, но тут нет склонений

Comment: Да, примерно то, что нужно, но может есть и другие варианты, где есть склонения?

Comment: @OwDafuq для склонений берите словарь opencorpora, например. Там по всем словам, но некоторые фамилии и имена есть.

Comment: Как вариант, спасибо, подумаем на него)